# Fancybox one gallery opened via multiple buttons

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox

I am using Fancybox for a work in progress photography site. This is the page that I have working: http://www.marybethmeehan.com/wordpress/portfolio/city-of-champions-project/

It works pretty well, but I have duplication in my gallery. The developer docs are pretty good, but for whatever reason I can't understand how to set this up. I bet it is pretty simple.

The page has three ways to open the one gallery.

- Click the Featured image (the girl in the band uniform)
- Click the number of images "35 images"
- Or click the "Thumbs" and click any image from there

When you click the featured image or the number of images, you get the first image in the gallery (which is perfect) BUT the image is actually duplicated. When you go forward form there, you see the same image again as gallery image number 2.

This is because I have use same anchor twice to initiate the gallery. Fancybox is doing what it is supposed to be doing I think. If you search the source for `616.downtown-from-above.jpg` you'll see it three times.

So, my simple question is, how do I start the gallery from whatever slide 1 is, without duplicating any contents of the gallery? I need to start the gallery from those two locations, plus allow someone to start anywhere they want via the thumbnail view. I'm sure I am just not understanding something very basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create custom click event for your "count link" and trigger click event for the first (or any other) image link. Something like this (do not forget to remove `data-fancybox` from count link):

```
jQuery('.project__gallery-wrapper__count a').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('[data-fancybox="mbm-gallery"]').first().trigger('click');
    return false;
});
```

btw, you could use fancyBox to display thumbnail list, similarly to this example - https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/#ajax

Comment: Ah… so I am sort of "faking" a click on fancybox itself with this method. That sort of makes sense. I though there might be a way to use the `fancybox().open()` method but couldn't figure out how to pass it the instance to open. Will try this, thanks.

Comment: "faking" click is perfectly fine technique. Actually, your question inspired me to add new feature to the upcoming fancyBox update, see last example here - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/full/VyLOJX/ (wait for next release or grab source code from the codepen :))

Comment: Well, that's awesome. Thanks for the great plug in. It really does work very well. I'm going to re-style the way the overlay works soon to match what my client wants. Seems like you have made it easy with the supplied CSS.